# Constructing a hexagonal heat-map with custom colors in each cell in google map(android)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, heatmap, hexagonal-tiles

How to construct a hexogonal shape heat map in google map.

Normally heat map in google map in constructed by following code

```
val heatMapProvider = HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
                    .weightedData(heatMapList)
                    .radius(50)
                    .build()
 mGoogleMap?.addTileOverlay(TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(heatMapProvider))
```

Where **heatmapList** is Arraylist of WeightedLatLng

And the output is something like below image
[image]

But my requirement is to create hexagon shape(honeycomb shape) heat map like below image

[image]

How to achieve hexagon shape heat map in google map.

Comment: Can I ask from what app did you see this hexagonal heatmap? I don't see this in the Maps SDK docs currently.

Comment: @Yrll, Bolt driver application did this heat map to represent the number of rides happening on particular area in google map. If Map SDK cannot have this function means. Any other possible way to achieve this functionality?